# mysqli connects to non existing (default?) host

Tags: php, mysqli

I came across a strange behaviour, which I can't explain myself. Maybe someone can help. These two single lines:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("");
print_r($mysqli);
```

give me this:

```
mysqli Object (
    [affected_rows] => 0
    [client_info] => 5.5.44
    [client_version] => 50544
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )
    [field_count] => 0
    [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.5.47-0+deb7u1
    [server_version] => 50547
    [stat] => Uptime: 950  Threads: 2  Questions: 1340  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 397  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 390  Queries per second avg: 1.410
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 393
    [warning_count] => 0
)
```

As you can see: `[connect_errno] => 0`
Which means that there is a valid connection.
I would prefer to have a connection error here. Isn't that a bit of a security risk?

Comment: Take a look at [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) (Hint: see Notes)

Comment: Yes, this *is* a security breach. In your mysql server. You should have set up a root password for it. While for PHP it's expected behavior.

Comment: That does not answer my questions. Ok, the notes tell me that localhost is the fallback default server. I can see that in the data_dump of the returned array. But of course the server has a root password. The question remains: What kind of connection is this?

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself, mysqli was able to open a valid connection to your MySQL server. This means that you have [an anonymous user set up on your MySQL server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4615/168229). This is a potential security risk from the side of database administration.

In terms of mysqli, it works as designed. All parameters in the constructor are optional. You only need to provide the first one which can also be `NULL` or an empty string in which case mysqli will fallback to local host. If no other values are provided in the constructor then mysqli will read values from INI configuration files. If the INI file doesn't have any values set up, then mysqli will fallback to default settings, which are an empty user with an empty password on localhost.